# apply() function to generate new value in a new column

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

I am new to python 3 and pandas. I tried to add a new column into a dataframe where the value is the difference between two existing columns. 
My current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from io import StringIO
x="""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9"""

with StringIO(x) as df:
    new=pd.read_csv(df)

print (new)

y=new.copy()

y.loc[:,"d"]=0

# My lambda function is completely wrong, but I don't know how to make it right.

y["d"]=y["d"].apply(lambda x:y["a"]-y["b"], axis=1)
```

Desired output is

a  b  c  d

1  2  3 -1

4  5  6 -1

7  8  9 -1

Does anyone have any idea how I can make my code work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `y` only for `DataFrame` for [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
y["d"]= y.apply(lambda x:x["a"]-x["b"], axis=1)
```

For better debugging is possible create custom function:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    a = x["a"]-x["b"]
    return a

y["d"]= y.apply(f, axis=1)

a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
a    4
b    5
c    6
Name: 1, dtype: int64
a    7
b    8
c    9
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

---

Better solution if need only subtract columns:

```
y["d"] = y["a"] - y["b"]

print (y)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3 -1
1  4  5  6 -1
2  7  8  9 -1
```

Comment: Thank so much for your reply. It really works. May I ask what x represents in this case? Does it mean each row of y?

Comment: Exactly, it s each row, because `axis=1`. If `axis=0`, it is each column.